# Retrieving part of URL in python

Tags: python

I'm on Python 3.6.
How I can extract part of URL so I can use it as variable.
For example, the URL is http://example.com/comp/**project**.sec and I would like to get the project part without .sec as variable.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

```
url = "http://example.com/comp/project.sec"
project = url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
```

Comment: Sorry 
    url = "http://example.com/comp/project.sec"

Comment: You can edit your answer to change that :)

Comment: @ViG thanks, bro =^_^=

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative, which removes `split` requirement.

```
from os.path import splitext, basename

splitext(basename('http://example.com/comp/project.sec'))[0]
```

Comment: `os.path.basename` on a URL?

Comment: This is much better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.urlparse("http://example.com/comp/project.sec").path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[-1]
```